# Azure DevOps .NET 5 - Publish results different from Visual Studio publish

Tags: azure-devops, orchardcms, .net-5, orchardcore

**EDIT / SOLUTION**

Turns out problem had nothing to do with the build pipeline. The git repo allowed two folders (wwwroot and WWWroot) in the same place but was only sending the wwwroot to my development machine. Suspect the build process was either prioritizing the other one which caused some of the resources (js css) to not be available - makes sense now that it was serving old versions, just did not at all make sense why). Even decompiling in dotPeek didn't help because the files (an and correct versions) were there, I just didn't notice the additional WWWroot and I guess OrchardCore must have prioritized that folder from the build... Sigh...

**END EDIT**

I am trying to get a publish of an OrchardCore website going in Azure Devops.
When I build/publish locally, the site runs fine. When I publish from Azure Devops, the results are just a little different. There are a small number of additional files and the dlls are generally a small number of KB different. I have tried lots (and lots) of options in Azure Devops to no success.

The result I am seeing is that the site is complaining that some css and js files are not available. When I disassembly with DotPeek, I see they are available, but I can't hit them from the browser. I have another project (an Orchard Core Theme) and it doesn't have any issues serving css and js files. I am 100% certain this is related to my devops yml. I am able to point my IIS from the UAT site (broken) to the drop for local, and it works, so I know it's not an IIS config issue.

Not sure I am even using the correct task objects VSBuild, MSBuild, DotNetCoreCLI?

Here is my current yml file:

```
parameters:
#this yml is used as a template, the pipeline script passes in the path to the csproj
- name: solution 
  type: string
  default: ''
   
steps:

- script: echo ${{ parameters.solution }}
          echo $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)


- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.8.x

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 5.0.x'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.x'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    includeNugetOrg: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Project'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    zipAfterPublish: true
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    #arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory) -f net5.0 --no-restore'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifacts (drop)'
  inputs:
    PathToPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

Comment: You're not deploying your application anywhere in the pipeline you posted. The size of the assemblies is irrelevant.

Comment: I have a release pipeline that pushes it down to my local machine. Is that what you mean? Or do I need a specific "deploy" type task in this yml?

Comment: @WillComeaux When you publish from Visual Studio, it will only publish one project (one csproj). The YAML file you have publish the solution, not the project. You should publish the project directly instead of publishing the solution.

Comment: @WillComeaux, You need to check if the files in the drop in the release pipeline are expected. Or you could share the configuration of your release pipeline.

Comment: I updated my yml files. Would it be best to edit my post above?
It now "builds" an entire solution (using  DotNetCoreCLI@2 with a build command) and a separate  DotNetCoreCLI@2 with a publish command of a single csproj.

The end result WRT to how the site behaves is identical. @Leo-liu-msft when I compare the local publish folder to the devops published one they are nearly identical. When I disassemble any given dll, they are identical except for the ID at the very top. 

devops folder has a .deps.json and an .runtimeconfig.json not in the other local publish folder.

Comment: Solved the issue. Somehow ended up with both a wwwroot and WWWroot folder in the project in question. Said folder never showed up in visual studio or on local disk when pulling the git repo. Only say it when browsing the repo directly. Deleting the WWWroot folder apparently was enough to clue Orchard Core in to where the resource files actually were... What a frustrating mess...

Comment: @WillComeaux, Thanks for your sharing and updating. Since you have resolved your question, would you please convert your comment to the answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading the answer, avoid spending a lot of time on a post that already has an answer. Thanks.